# Rails cannot update column value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have created Rails(version 3.2) application with mysql database. I have table **Message** with column content. I can update the following data using rails console but I can't using run same code from seeds.rb.

data: "Join **** Audio / Video Meeting. This is an online meeting by ****, the community marketplace to find products and services in your neighbourhood. http://*****.dev:3000/conferences/80"

I have following code in my seeds.rb file

```
all_messages = Message.all

all_messages.each do |message|
  message_content = message.content
  if message_content.present? && message_content[/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/conferences/,2].present?
    message_content.slice! (message_content[/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/conferences/,2]+'/')
    if message.update_attributes!(content: message_content)
      puts message.content
    else
      puts "nothing"
    end
  end
end
```

It does't show any errors, but data is not updated in db and not shown any errors.

This is my model file

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  after_save :update_conversation_read_status

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "Person"
  belongs_to :conversation
  has_one :request

  validates_presence_of :sender_id
  validates_presence_of :content

  def update_conversation_read_status
    conversation.update_attribute(:last_message_at, created_at)
    conversation.participations.each do |p|
      last_at = p.person.eql?(sender) ? :last_sent_at : :last_received_at
      p.update_attributes({ :is_read => p.person.eql?(sender), last_at => created_at})
    end
  end
end
```

**Note**: content is text type in db.

Comment: You have two `puts` statement in seeds file so while you are running it is anything printed on the console?

Comment: Deep: I have solved my problem. The problem is using slice! method.

Comment: Aah `slice!` was returning `nil` or something like that?

Comment: `slice!` returns string with double quotes. That is the problem.